# Spyder complains "torch" module is not found

Tags: spyder, torch

I am trying to run a file with 'torch' module in it. However, when I arrive at a line that contains:

```
training_set = torch.FloatTensor(training_set)
test_set = torch.FloatTensor(test_set)
```

it pops out the error that 'torch' is 'ModuleNotFoundError'

The below screenshots shows the pop-up error and I also checked whether 'torch' is up to date.
I am using Spyder
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue in Spyder: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16348

For the moment, as a workaround, you can enable the option `Exclude unsupported data types` from the Variable Explorer options menu

Comment: I checked that link, it is the same issue. However, it didn't solve my problem

Comment: I think that now you are facing another different issue from the [screenshot you posted in Github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16348#issuecomment-954207855) (this time related related to the type of variable you are trying to visualize)

Comment: Yes, the error shown in the screenshot here https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16348#issuecomment-954207855 is only shown when the line tensor.FloatTEnsor is run